# List of tuple or list as feature in a classifier:Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I am trying to build a classifier with a variety of features.The kind of features are like:

```
feat1='foo'
feat2=['foo','bar']
feat3=[('foo','bar','foo'),('back','front','back')]
```

How do I incorporate all of these as features for a classifier? I am using `sklearn.svm.SVC`

When I tried doing,

```
clf=OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel='linear',probability=True,random_state=random_state))
X_train=np.array([feat1,feat2,feat3]).T
y_score = clf.fit(X_train, y_train).decision_function(X_test)
```

it gave me the following error while trying to fit to the classifier

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Any thoughts or ideas as to how to include these features/vectorize them would be useful

Comment: You get this error because you are using feat1,feat2,feat3 with different lengths at the `X_train` line

Comment: @Val - it is not only this. SVM does not accept strings as inputs.

Comment: One would need more info in order to be able to provide an efficient vectorisation of your input. For example, is the length of each feature fixed? What exactly a "feature" do represent in your scheme? What exactly the values within the lists do represent? How many of them do exist?